# Extend struct in Go

Tags: go

Suppose object A has a field of type [`net.Dialer`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer). I'd like to provide object A with a custom implementation of `net.Dialer` that augments the `Dial` method. Is this doable in Go? I'm trying to use [*embedded fields*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) like so:

```
package main

import (
    "net"
    "fmt"
)

type dialerConsumer struct {
    dialer net.Dialer
}

func (dc *dialerConsumer) use() error {
    conn, e := dc.dialer.Dial("tcp", "golang.org:http")
    if e != nil {
        return e
    }

    fmt.Printf("conn: %s\n", conn)
    return nil
}

type customDialer struct {
    net.Dialer
}

func main() {
    standardDialer := net.Dialer{}
    consumer := &dialerConsumer{
        dialer: standardDialer,
    }
    consumer.use()


    /*
    customDialer := customDialer{
        net.Dialer{},
    }
    consumer = &dialerConsumer{
        dialer: customDialer,
    }
    consumer.use()
    */
}
```

However, when I uncomment the commented-out code in `main`, I get the following compilation error:

```
src/test.go:38: cannot use customDialer (type customDialer) as type net.Dialer in field value
```

Answer (score 6):

You're getting the error because `customDialer` and `net.Dialer` are two different types and cannot be used interchangeably. Embedding in Go is not the same as class inheritance in other OO langauges so it won't help you with what you trying to do.

What you can do instead in this case is to use Go interfaces which give you something like polymorphism/duck-typing, and since interfaces in Go are satified implicitly you can define a new interface that an existing type will implement by virtue of having a method with the same signature as the newly defined interface.

```
// already implemented by net.Dialer
type Dialer interface {
    Dial(network, address string) (net.Conn, error)
}

type customDialer struct {
    *net.Dialer
}

func (cd *customDialer) Dial(network, address string) (net.Conn, error) {
    conn, err := cd.Dialer.Dial(network, address)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Printf("conn: %s\n", conn)
    return conn, nil
}

// now the dialer field can be set to *customDialer and net.Dialer as well
type dialerConsumer struct {
    dialer Dialer
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/i3Vpsh3wii

Comment: Appreciate the answer, unfortunately if I'm reading it correctly, `net.Dialer` is defined as a struct and not an interface: https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer I also should mention that I have no control over object A, so I cannot modify it to say, use a new interface that could include Dialer's public methods, `Dial` and `DialContext`.

Comment: If you have no control over `A`, then you're right, you cannot assign the `Dialer` interface to it, and you cannot in Go assign anything else besides `net.Dialer` to a field of type `net.Dialer`... Next best thing is wrapping object `A` and doing whatever you need to do before calling `Dial`.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, wrapping A seems like my only option at the moment. Thanks for the feedback!